# Bluetooth headphones audio gets out of sync

Tags: audio, sync, bluetooth

I recently bought the Mixcder 104 bluetooth headphones. I've noticed that sometimes the audio gets out of sync by a second or so. This happens for all audio output - video, games, etc. and remains until I disconnect and reconnect the headphones.

How can I prevent  losing the sync?

Comment: model and brand of headphones would be an awesome thing to add to your question.

Comment: @Sickest Sorry, added that

Comment: have your tried to replace the unit or call the company?

Comment: Not yet, but it would be easier if there was something I can do. Hence me asking here.